# How do I properly use convert_tz() within a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to eliminate a bug stemming from timezone issues and I'm having trouble getting convert_tz() to work properly. I suspect it may just be a syntax error.

```
SUM(IF(duration IS NULL, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(convert_tz(t.start_time,'$instanceTimezone','$serverTimezone')), duration)) as `dailyTime`,
```

I'm trying to set duration to be Now - t.start_time when the query is run.

Unfortunately the times in this database are not stored in a standardized way so I have to convert from the instance timezone to the server time for the calculation. The server time should always be in UTC but I've left it in a variable take from some params just in case.

I do have the mysql timezones loaded and have set my local testing instance to use UTC time.

When using it like this I'm not getting any errors. But it always returns 0 for the duration.

Comment: Yes, this is in PHP. I had that tagged originally but someone edited it out. I guess because the question itself doesn't directly relate to PHP.

Comment: Can you include example data for t.start_time, the column datatype and the expression exactly as it is submitted to the db (with $variables expanded)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here had to do with the timezone tables I had loaded in to mysql.

I loaded them in from OSX and the name for UTC was Etc/UTC. Changing my local mysql timezone tables to match the server value of UTC fixed the issue.